# Can I have a javascript object remove itself from memory by having it set its map value to null?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, memory-management

Would the game object remove itself from memory when kill game is called?

```
var GamesMap = {};
var count = 0;

function Game (players, privateGame) {
        if (privateGame) this.privateGame = true;
        else this.privateGame = false;
        this._id = count++;
        this.players = players;
        this.judge = this.setJudge();

        this.killGame() = function() {
                GamesMap[this._id] = null;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no other references to that particular `Game` object (including event handlers and other lasting things like that), then clearing the last reference to it by clearing its reference in the `GamesMap` will make it eligible for garbage collection when the `killGame()` method finishes executing.  But, the very fact that you are able to call `obj.killGame()` means that somebody else has a reference to it so that reference needs to be released too.

I would suggest that rather than set the property to `null` that you actually delete the property in the map like this:

```
delete GamesMap[this._id];
```

so you're cleaning up fully after a game is done.

Comment: What would be the advantages of deleting the property

Comment: @DanielKobe - It just seems like the proper way to clean up after a game is done.  If the game is done and gone, then why keep an empty property around that used to refer to it?  And, if you want to iterate games underway, you will then have to add an extra test to see if the iterated property is `null`.  If you delete the property, then the only properties present are the games underway.  And, an empty property does take some space though probably not significant - but just seems cleaner to get rid of things you no longer need.